# Flex: horizontally goes beyond the screen

Tags: css, flexbox

Everything is ok, but with a smaller screen I want it to be center aligned, it gets center aligned, but there is also a space beyond the screen appears.

Code:

```css
.example {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #363636;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 353px;
  padding: 26px 0 0 0;
}
.example-links {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
}
.example-1 {
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  padding: 0 69px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.example-2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 52px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
  column-gap: 52px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 44px;
  position: relative;
}
.example-networks {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  margin-left: 74px;
  -moz-column-gap: 52px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
  column-gap: 83px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .example-links {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .example-1 {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .example-2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 52px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
    column-gap: 52px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .example-3 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    margin-left: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 52px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
    column-gap: 83px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="example">
  <section class="example-links">
    <ul class="example-1">
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="example-2">
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="example-3">
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Eisenhansel/gmnff17y/

Comment: Sorry, Im trying to add the code, but it says there is too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine. Just modify class `.example-links` css used `max-width` instead of `width` like this:

```
.example-links {
  max-width: 960px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```css
.example {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #363636;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 353px;
  padding: 26px 0 0 0;
}
.example-links {
  max-width: 960px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
}
.example-1 {
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  padding: 0 69px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.example-2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 52px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
  column-gap: 52px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 44px;
  position: relative;
}
.example-networks {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  margin-left: 74px;
  -moz-column-gap: 52px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
  column-gap: 83px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .example-links {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .example-1 {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .example-2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 52px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
    column-gap: 52px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .example-3 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    margin-left: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 52px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
    column-gap: 83px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="example">
  <section class="example-links">
    <ul class="example-1">
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="example-2">
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="example-3">
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
      <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)